# Comparison sign 'greater than' in CASE SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to do comparison within a case statement.
I've tried:

```
CASE DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDate, rs.PaymentDate) >1 AND <2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneMonthDelay
,CASE DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDate, rs.PaymentDate) >2 AND <3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoMonthDelay
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your logic makes no sense.  There are no integers > 1 and < 2, nor > 2 and < 3.  Both conditions would always return 0, even if syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their point is INTEGERS are whole numbers. Therefore, nothing is ever GREATER than 1 AND SMALLER than 2, but there is EQUAL TO OR GREATER/LESS logic. If an item is to be GREATER than 1 but SMALLER than 2, it has to be a something like a decimal (1.1, 1.2, 1.201...)

Based off of your logic:

```
LOGIC: >1 <2
INPUT: 1
RESULT: 0
```

Because 1 is not GREATER than 1 AND LESS than 2. 1 is EQUAL to 1, but 1.01 is GREATER than 1

```
LOGIC => 1 =< 2 
INPUT: 1
RESULT: 1
```

Alternatively, I think you can do (someone might have to correct me on this)

EDIT:

Using juergen d's logic (Final edit, this should work):

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID)
BETWEEN 1 AND 2    
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS OneMonthDelay
```

Your whole query should look like:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID)
BETWEEN 1 AND 2    
THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END AS OneMonthDelay,
CASE WHEN
DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID)
BETWEEN 2 AND 3
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS TwoMonthDelay
FROM FooTable
```

Comment: Updated, using juergen d's query

Comment: The edit is what @juergen suggested, but not works. It's marked as an error in Management Studio.

Comment: Nope, I can't do a printscreen via TeamViewer (remote desktop). But it returns "Incorrect syntax near 'BETWEEN'".

Comment: Please post your whole query, I expect it to look something like:

    SELECT
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,  rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID)
    BETWEEN 1 AND 2    
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS OneMonthDelay
    FROM FooTable

Comment: Please look at my final 'whole query' edit for reference. Or show yours, thanks. I think you were missing 'WHEN' without seeing your query, because you did not include it in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID) > 1  
      AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID) < 2 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END AS OneMonthDelay
```

which makes by the way no sense (`>1 <2`)

Comment: What do you mean "no sense >1 <2"?

Comment: Your condition can never be true because the result can not be greater than 1 and also be smaller than 2.

Comment: Why not? The purpose of that statement is to count payments made with 1 month delay (within interval 1-2 month from scheduled payment date)

Comment: So what number is greater than 1 and smaller than 2 using only integer numbers?

Comment: Yep...you noticed that ID :-) I simplified the query for the purpose of the question.

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` returns an integer. for instance 1 or 2 or 3 or 0. think about it

Comment: I'm still not getting the point. 
DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-03) will return 1, correct?

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried only DATEDIFF(MONTH, rs.MaturityDateID, rs.PaymentDateID) > 1 THEN.... and it seems not to accept the statement either.

Comment: If datediff() returns 1 then is this result greather than 1? No. So your condition should be `> 1 OR < 2` (and not `> 1 AND < 2`) or whatever you want to accomplish.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. As Simon suggested, function BETWEEN should be used.